# Couldn't open Git Shell in Windows 10! How to open Posh-Git?

Tags: git, github, git-shell

Very new to Git Hub and Git Shell. I have installed GitHub using GitHubSetup.exe from https://desktop.github.com/. It created shortcuts for GitHub and Git Shell on my desktop and I am able to clone my repository to C:\ drive too. But when I open my repository using Git Shell, its not opening. Instead its showing some tasks like Run as Admin, Windows PowerShell (x86) etc.
[image]

I tried to Run as Admin, but its opening PowerShell.
[image]

How could I open Posh-Git?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those tasks are associated to a Powershell icon. Not to GitHub Desktop.
It has nothing to do with Git.

You need to use the GitHub Desktop wheel at the top right corner, to open a git shell:

[image: git shell]

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I was right clicking on wrong icon, I guess. My fault! :)